# Is `firebase-core` required for Firebase on Android?

Tags: android, firebase

As far as I know, individual Firebase libraries like `firebase-auth` didn't used to require me to include `firebase-core`.

However, I recently started a new Android project, and when I tried to build without `firebase-core`, I got the following Java compiler warning:

`Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.`

Comment: For those who still looking for documentation about its removal: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#core_v21-1-1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE**: AUGUST 2019

[*The docs now show whether a specific product SDK **requires** `firebase-analytics`, if `firebase-analytics` is **recommended***, or if it is not needed at all.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries)

`firebase-core` is no longer listed as a required dependency in the Android getting started guide and was removed from the [list of available libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries).

Now adding `firebase-analytics` to your app is [optional in the getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-sdks). Products that do require `firebase-core`, [such as In-App Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=android#add_the_sdk_to_your_project), list the `firebase-core` dependency in their setup guides.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

This is a recent change as of May 23, 2018. Per the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_may_23_2018):

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

This requirement is reflected in the "Set up {X} for Android" guides ([example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)) in the step "Install the Firebase SDK". That step links to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase), which includes the requirement to add `firebase-core`.

*edit 9/26/18:* A summary of features that rely on Google Analytics for Firebase (and therefore `firebase-core`) can be found [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6383877?hl=en#features).

Comment: I'm not a fan of this answer. Yes google says we should put it in, but if it's actually mandatory, why didn't google make it a required dependency in the maven POM file? Why make everyone explicitly reference it for no reason?
This is doubly suspicous, because firebase-core is actually just google analytics for firebase; personally I want NOTHING to do with google analytics and it's privacy invading user-tracking, but can I really opt-out here? We use firebase-messaging as it's required to send push notifications to android

Comment: Firebaser here. That's a good comment! Where we have a hard dependency, we do add it as a POM dep. However, there are a bunch of services that have soft dependencies (FCM, Remote Config, Predictions, A/B Testing, Crashlytics etc.) where Analytics adds a lot of value. You can disable analytics tracking (https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics), which will mean you get enable it only if you have consent etc.

Comment: @IanBarber Thanks for explaining, but will keeping out `firebase-core`/`firebase-analytics` do any harm to the things that have soft dependencies?

Comment: @IanBarber I'm asking this because you are basically saying:
 "Analytics is useful so you must add the dependency, if you don't like it you can disable it".

Why not leave it out in the first place then?

Comment: @IanBarber I am in a similar situation.  I am only using FCM and everything seems to work without firebase-core dependency but I get the warning.  Can I ignore the warning?  I don't want to have to add additional dependencies if they don't actually do anything.  Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore the warning with FCM, but it will stop some reporting of messaging open stats etc. in some cases.

Comment: But I get this warning for a module in my project which doesn't use any other dependency than support annotations. How come it is depending on Firebase?

Comment: Same issue! I would like to ignore the warning. How can I do it?

Comment: If I try to upgrade firebase.core to anything higher than 16.0.9, I get a compile killing merge error with support-v4, so have had to leave it at 16.0.9. I'm not geek enough to fix the error from the support-v4 end so may have to just drop analytics. Attempting to upgrade .auth and .database from 17.0.0 also causes the merge error.

Answer (score -3):

Using the 16.0.6 version the warning gone away

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he/she is saying that they don't want to add the core dependency as they aren't even using it, so why would adding it be a solution?

Comment: Which file do we add this line to and where in the file?

Comment: This does not answer the question in hand.