# Do I need Firebase Core for Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use only Firebase Database and I've added only the next dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

it seems works ok

but during compilation I get next warning

> Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as
>   intended.

Should I still add Core? like:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is \`firebase-core\` required for Firebase on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765554/is-firebase-core-required-for-firebase-on-android)

Comment: @TheIT just mark it as duplicate then, no need to down vote

Comment: Agreed, I didn't downvote though :(

Comment: @TheIT ah.. ok. Sorry.

Comment: Another SO entry that was supposedly a duplicate of this one sent me here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52685463/gradle-must-have-dependency-on-com-google-firebasefirebase-core-for-firebase-se) and this one really isn't a duplicate of the one mentioned at the top of these comments, instead this one is the best answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have to explicitly list it now:

> Update - June 12, 2018
>
> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android