# Gradle must have Dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

While compiling I'm getting a warning like this,

The app Gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.

just add the below line

updated

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
```

Comment: firebase-core is required for firebase analytics.

Comment: here is the hint for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586177/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core16-0-1

Answer (score 7):

I think your Gradle file has the below `implementation` missing. Add this to your app-level `build.gradle` file

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
```