# App crashing on andorid phone for firebase usage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing the realtime database of firebase.
The app crashes on launch.
I have the following dependencies in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

I looked for other questions and some suggested if it might be because of dependencies. Where can I see the compatible dependencies if it is because of that because I am getting a warning

> The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.

I am following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM2x33g4syY&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hj6SDHf_YybDeVhUT9MXaj1
Someone commented to use "private" in the model class. So I used that for the variable of the Artist class. But it didn't work.
I did not do anything different than this tutorial.

**Update 1**
After adding the firebase-core dependency, I get the following error for build

> ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

**Update 2**
I changed all the dependencies to the latest version by following official docs

1. firebase-core:16.0.7
2. firebase-database:16.0.6

at the end of the file I also added

1. apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and in build.gradle I updated this to

1. google-services:4.2.0

It solved the build issue but the app still crashes.

Comment: I have created apps with firebase before but now I am getting an error, can you add to the post your error?. It will help me compare the problem and will be easier to help you.

Comment: @guy updated the post with the error message

Comment: Why is the crash?

Comment: @SonaliGupta what's the new error that your getting? share it in the post

Comment: Trying to figure that out

Answer (score 1):

As of the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765554/is-firebase-core-required-for-firebase-on-android) you are required to add the `firebase-core` to gradle file before any other Firebase dependency.
add this before `firebase-database` dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
```

Comment: Simply adding this doesn't work. Is there no place to know all dependencies it might need version wise. Build fails with ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: I found this list but can't decide which one for realtime db https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: those are not firebase dependencies, check the docs link in my post and follow the instruction on how to setup firebase in your app, and the docs includes list of all firebase dependencies

Comment: Yes I did that. I setup it through the tools and not manually. Realtime database needs core and database dependencies which are added. Is there something I am Missing

Comment: no that should be enough, but if your still having error, share them

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) you should add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'` in the build.gradle file.

You can as well update your version of the firebase-database (Realtime Database) to 16.0.6 `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'`

To check the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` you should look at the first build.gradle file

```
buildscript{
repositories{...}
dependencies{
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}
```

Check if the version is 4.2.0

Comment: @SonaliGupta one problem at a time ;)

Comment: @SonaliGupta if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @SonaliGupta If you have new error you should open new question for the specific one, This way if someone search the answer he can use this post.